# How to create file validation shell script?

Tags: file, shell, file-io

I have a list of text files in a particular directory and file names in a text file.

How do I verify whether the files in the text file are present in that particular directory?

Comment: which language are u using

Comment: Is the text file set up in a way that you could reasonably loop over the entries? E.g. In bash, I you do: for i in 'cat file'; do echo $i; done  would you get one file name per line of output? O is here some other separator like a comma that needs to be split off?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple, and assuming that by "shell" you mean a Unix shell:

```
ls -1 path/to/directory | sort > list1.txt
sort file_with_filenames.txt > list2.txt
diff list1.txt list2.txt
```

You can probably tweak this into a smart loop or one-liner, but for a one-shot problem this should suffice. Upside is that you don't have to worry about spaces in filenames, which can make looping solutions rather tricky.

You can use the return code from `diff` to break if there are any differences.

Since you didn't state any specific requirements, I didn't bother with things like

- creating the list files in /tmp
- making this re-entrant (e.g. by including PID in the temporary filenames)
- cleaning up the temporary files afterwards
- do sanity checks (existence of directory / filelist etc.)

"Production" quality code should add all those, of course.